# What is the name of Stark's element in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2

In *Iron Man 2*, Tony Stark has the problem of poisoning from his Arc Reactor. He stops this by

> synthesizing a new element, with instructions from his father, Howard Stark.

The new element was created and in the comics was actually Vibranium! However, in the MCU, it's definitely not; so what is it called? I've heard extrapolations that it was called Starkium, and based on Tony's personality, that would make sense. Is there any official reveal of the name?

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect as it is an older question, however, my answer is up to date. Tony wanted to call it Badassium though ran into legal issues. We don't know anything beyond that.